# How can I set LLDB's default language to Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, lldb

I have a large Swift project that's technically a mixed project, as it has a small amount of Objective-C code. But whenever I drop into LLDB, the expression evaluator is expecting Objective-C syntax. I can use Swift with `e -l swift --` but this is tedious to type every time.

Can I default the LLDB expression evaluator to Swift?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a target level setting to force the language:

```
(lldb) settings set target.language swift
```

Or you can make an alias for swift specific expressions:

```
command alias es expression -l swift --
```

Comment: Jim or @Bill is there any way I can add `command alias es expression -l swift --` to some alias table so it is persistent on every xCode debug session?

Comment: Save it to ~/.llbinit