# Switch to Objective-C mode in lldb

Tags: ios, lldb

When I am debugging a Swift app in Xcode, the debugger expects expressions in Swift format. How can I switch it to expect Objective-C expressions instead?

E.g., I want to be able to type `expr id $foo = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithBar:@"quux"];` instead of whatever the Swift equivalent is.

Comment: This is the same answer as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390238/how-can-i-set-lldbs-default-language-to-swift but swift -> objc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Swift 3.0 or before use:** 
You can use the following command to identify the name of all available languages in LLDB.

[image: (lldb)help <language>]

**Swift 4.0**

[image: (lldb)help <source-language>]

**Create an alias like "eco" to print objective-c objects:**

```
(lldb)command alias eco expression -l objective-c -o --
(lldb)eco [[UIApplication sharedApplication] userHomeDirectory] 
/Users/...
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore (Xcode 9.3): `(lldb) help <language>` _(linebreak)_
`error: '<language>' is not a known command.` _(linebreak)_
`Try 'help' to see a current list of commands.` _(linebreak)_
`Try 'apropos <language>' for a list of related commands.` _(linebreak)_
`Try 'type lookup <language>' for information on types, methods, functions, modules, etc.`

Answer (score 12):

[Advanced debugging with Xcode and LLDB](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/412/) from WWDC 2018, shows that this can be done with the following command:

```
expression -l objc -O -- [doYourStuff here]
```

but there is an important thing to note here, switching from a Swift to an Objective C frame creates a *new context*. In practice this means that you will probably get an error like:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'self'
```

to avoid this problem you need to enclose any varables, that need to be evaluated before the context change, in backticks `` ` ``. For example:

```
expression -l objc -O -- [`self` class]
```

Comment: Xcode 12 gives me: use of undeclared identifier 'l'