# LLDB alias for Swift command

Tags: swift, lldb

When debugging SQLite queries from [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) in my app, I sometimes use a command to return all the values in the current row of the result set:

```
(lldb) po (0..<result.columnCount()).map{result.object(forColumnIndex: $0)!}
```

I use the name "result" consistently throughout my app, so this command never changes, and obviously it's a little tedious to type it out every time I want to use it so I wanted to create an alias, but when I try to do so (whether through a .lldbinit file or directly in the Xcode console), I get an error:

```
(lldb) command alias poresult po (0..<result.columnCount()).map{result.object(forColumnIndex: $0)!}
error: Unable to create requested alias.
```

Looking around, I couldn't find any instances of using Swift code in an alias, but I did find several examples with Objective-C, so I assume it's possible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try replacing `po` in your alias with `expression -l swift --`

Comment: @Alexander That allowed me to create the alias, but the output isn't useful.

Comment: Opps, I meant `expression -O -l swift --`

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what it needed.  Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390238/how-can-i-set-lldbs-default-language-to-swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Swift project, `po` is an alias for `expression -O -l swift --`. Try substituting it for its definition in your own alias.

```
command alias poresult expression -O -l swift -- (0..<result.columnCount()).map{result.object(forColumnIndex: $0)!}
```

More general:

```
command alias ALIAS_NAME expression -O -l swift -- YOUR_CODE_HERE
```